# Overcoming Inbreeding Depression

Tags: genetics, animal-husbandry

When inbreeding depression occurs, a genetically unrelated individual is mated with the animal to introduce genetic variability and remove homozygosity. In this case either outbreeding or crossbreeding may be carried out. Is there any preference for either technique over the other? 
Out-breeding here refers to mating between two individuals in the same breed, but no recent common ancestors. 
Cross-breeding refers to mating between two individuals of different breeds entirely.

Comment: can you clarify language? Is it that outcrossing is mating between different populations, whereas crossbreeding is mating between members of inbred populations? E.g. mating between european and asian peasants _versus_ mating between members of european and asian royal families.

Comment: [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbreed) mentions both outcrossing and crossbreeding. Language seems confusing to me

Comment: I don't think there is any accepted clear definitions of outbreeding vs crossbreeding. Therefore, definitions should be provided in the post.

Comment: @Remi.b my point exactly. Although, broadly, if you cross inbre(a)d species, you get less variation than crossing more wild-typish (forgive me) animals